# Insert roughness symbol by macro in catia

Tags: macros, symbols, catia

I know a little about macro in Catia. I want to insert roughness symbol in drawing document by macro. I tried to find out it on internet but I can't. I hope anyone can help me. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API for this. Try to draw it. Still, you can check in v5automation.chm file if there is something new for your CATIA version.